# How far (and shortest route) from SFO International arrivals to the Departures level

Tags: sfo

Apparently Uber pickups are supposed to happen on the Departures level. A friend is somewhat handicapped due to carpal tunnel.

( a ) would there likely be an exception made.

( b ) if not then what would be the shortest distance for them to get to the Uber pickup location on departures level

This is for Singapore Airlines.

Comment: Which wing of the international terminal (A or G), or which airline?

Comment: @Doc Updated OP.  Nowhere I look talks about which "wing" - only that it is International Terminal.

Comment: Singapore Airlines is International G

Comment: An exception is unfortunately pretty unlikely I think. The airport authorities require Uher and Lyft drivers to only use the departures level and can fine the drivers for violating this rule. Other alternatives would be a taxicab, which pickup on the arrivals level, or your friend could request a wheelchair from the airline, which should be waiting for them at the gate when the flight arrives. He or she can ask the wheelchair attendant to take them upstairs after exiting customs.

Comment: It's worth noting that proceeding to the departures level after customs is hardly an obscure move off the beaten path. You need to do that to reach BART too, and if you're taking the AirTrain to the car rental center you have to do that and continue yet a level up.

Comment: @Doc: Won't passengers arriving at the two sides of the terminal be herded towards a common immigration hall anyway?

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, there are two immigration/customs areas, one for each wing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Singapore Airlines flights arrive into the G wing of the International terminal at SFO.

The Departure level is located directly above the arrivals level.  After going through immigration and collecting bags, your friend will pass through customs who will direct her to the exit on the right-hand side (the other side is for connecting flights).

After following the path (it snakes around a little) they will exit into the public area of the terminal.  The exits will be directly in front of them, but they should NOT go through them as that's the wrong level.

Instead, turn right, walk maybe 20 metres/yards, and they will come to an escalator going up (slight off to the right, but it's very obvious).  Once at the top of the escalator they will be on the departure level - loop around to the left and the exit will be very obvious.  There's also an information desk at the top of the escalator (just off to the left) who will be happy to help.

If they'd prefer to avoid the escalator, a few metres/yards past the escalators on the left are the elevators/lifts - just select Up and then the Departures floor (the same elevators also go down to the parking garages)

When booking the Uber they'll need to select what door they are at - International Departures Door 5 will be the nearest if they follow these instructions.